# Terminology concerning conjugation in groups of functions.

Tags: group-theory, category-theory, terminology

If there is a function $a$ such that $a\circ g\circ a^{-1}=h$ then **the functions $g$ and $h$ are conjugate to each other**.

- If one wished to identify $a$, would one say "$g$ and $h$ are conjugate "**by** $a$" or "**via** $a$" or the like?  What locution is most customary here?  (Yes, one can write $a\circ g\circ a^{-1}=h$ as above, but some contexts make a more verbal style appropriate.)
- Is there a standard short name for the relation between $g$ and $h$ that for some involution $a$ (i.e. $a=a^{-1}$), $a\circ g\circ a = h$?  Can one say "$g$ and $h$ are blahblah" or "$g$ is blahblah to $h$", where "blahblah" is something terse, like the word "conjugate"?
- Is there a standard name for a function that is conjugate to its own inverse?
- Is there a standard name for a function that is conjugate to its own inverse via an involution?
- If the answer to the foregoing is affirmative, one may wish to identify which involution it is in a verbal statement, e.g. "$g$ is blahblahblah via $a$".  Is there some conventional verbiage for that?

(I've added a "category theory" tag because I think those writing about that topic may be the people with the most frequent occasion to use this kind of language.)

Comment: I would say "$g$ and $h$ are conjugate **via** a" although I'm not sure if that's a standard practice - I don't think I've taken notice before. If a function $g$ is conjugate to its own inverse via an involution $a$ then $aga=g^{-1}\iff ga=a^{-1}g^{-1}=(ga)^{-1}$ so maybe saying "$ga$ is an involution" would be enough?

Comment: @DanielRust : Well, that last idea doesn't really focus the attention where I want it.  I've noticed that if $a\circ g\circ a = g^{-1}$ then $g\circ a\circ g = a^{-1}$, but that doesn't mean $g$ and $a$ play symmetrical roles in my last bulleted point above, since $g$ is not generally an involution.

Comment: Concrete example: for $x\in\mathbb Z$, $x\overset{g}{\mapsto} x+c$ and $x\overset{a}{\mapsto} -x$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: In a group, an element that is conjuagte to its own inverse is called a 'real' element, and one conjugate to its inverse by an involution is a 'strongly real' element.

Comment: @aPaulT : Your comment is the only one that addresses what for me is the main question.  If you can cite one or more sources, maybe you should make your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a group, an element that's conjugate to its inverse is called a 'real' element (see [here](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Real_element)) and one conjugate to its inverse via an involution is called 'strongly real' (see [here](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Strongly_real_element)).